# how to set background image in android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

i want have an image and i want to set it as a background of android list view

i have used android:background="drawable/image"  but nothing happened

can any one guide me how to achieve this?

any help would be appricated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhops

android:background="@drawable/image"

noticing the @

Also make sure your project's res/drawable folder contains a valid image file called image.jpg or image.png.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if other formats are supported, but those are the recommended formats and in my opinion will cover most of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jim, clean  or re-open the project to ensure your newly added image file gets reflected in the /res/drawable folder

Comment: Or just select the 'drawable' directory and press F5.